# how do I convert text to integer in Java

Tags: java

I am trying to figure out how to convert text from text fields into intergers in Eclipse.
here is what I have so far, and it's been a few days since I have worked on this program and I am also new to java coding. If I have the code I need in here already, I apologize in advance for asking this question.

```
protected void do_enterButton_actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    int scr1, scr2, scr3 = -1;
    TestScores score = (TestScores)studentList.getSelectedValue();
    int score1 = Integer.parseInt(score1TextField.getText());
    score.setScore1(score1);
    int score2 = Integer.parseInt(score2TextField.getText());
    score.setScore2(score2);
    int score3 = Integer.parseInt(score3TextField.getText());
    score.setScore3(score3);

    if (score1TextField != null) {
        // this is where I need to convert to text to integer
    }
```

Comment: Haven't you already answewred your own question several lines prior?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert string to int in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585779/how-to-convert-string-to-int-in-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`score1` is where you already did the conversion. `Integer.parseInt(score1TextField.getText());` was correct.

Comment: thank you! last time I tried it, it gave me an error, but now I think I know why

Comment: Perhaps the string wasn't parseable into an integer, or the `getText()` call was unnecessary or failed on a `null`. In fact, I don't even see where `score1TextField` gets declared. I'm surprised you didn't get a compiler error.

Comment: sorry, I have A LOT of code and didn't want to bore people with all of it, text fields are declared at the start of the program so everything can access them when needed

Answer (score 0):

The Integer.parseInt() you have in there converts text (String values or char sequences) to integer.

You should encase those in a try-catch block though.

```
    try{
    test = Integer.parseInt(textval);
    }catch(NumberFormatException e){
    System.out.println("A number was expected but not found.");
    test = 0;
    }
```